# Windows 10 install from usb drive - boots up but freezes

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive, windows-installation, windows-installer

I'm trying to do a clean install of Windows 10 from a usb drive.

*Problem: The system boots up and presents the first Windows setup screen (where I'm supposed to choose language, time- and currency format and keyboard). I can move the mouse pointer but after a few seconds the system freezes. If I use the keyboard instead a can press 5-15 keys before the system freezes.*

I have tried to boot both uefi and legacy - same result. I have tried putting the mouse (and keyboard) in usb 2.0 and usb 3.0 ports - same result.

My thoughts is that this is a usb driver problem but I have no idea on how to proceed.

Comment: probably not a driver problem - may be with the installation media itself; try making a new bootable file or using a different USB drive

Comment: I have redone it several times using Microsoft Media Creation Tool and Rufus. Have used the same usb stick though, do you mean that the media itself might be faulty? Seems unlikely but I'll try again with another stick.

Comment: it's worth a shot - it's weird for it to boot fine but freeze. is your USB drive an external HDD or some sort of flash?

Comment: It's a usb flash drive and it was nothing wrong with it. I tried another one with the same result.

Comment: have you tried putting the boot device in a different USB drive?

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be a bug i BIOS. After updating BIOS in my motherboard (Gigabyte Z390 AORUS PRO WIFI) to the latest version everything is ok.